¿Como insertar datos con python a postgreSql?
Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de insertar datos de pruebas a mi base de postgreSql.
La estructura de mi BD es asi:
create table pagedetail(
    vmoNonAmpSupportedText char(20)
)

Esta es mi clase donde estoy creando el método para insertar:
import psycopg2
import os
class Operations:
def getConnection():
    try:
        conexion = psycopg2.connect(
            host=os.environ['HOST'],
            database=os.environ['DATABASE'],
            user=os.environ['USER'],
            password=os.environ['PASSWORD']
        )
        return conexion
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as error:
        print(f"Error al conectar a la base de datos: {error}")
        return None

def insertPageDetail():
    conn = Operations.getConnection()

    if conn is not None:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            sql = """
                INSERT INTO pagedetail (vmoNonAmpSupportedText)
                VALUES (%s)
            """

            datos = ('Hola')
            cursor.execute(sql, datos)

            conn.commit()



        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Hubó un error: {e}")
            conn.rollback()
            return None

Pero no logró insertar los datos y me sale el siguiente error siempre not all arguments converted during string formatting ya lo intente convirtiendo mi datos con str() pero sigo sin poder tener éxito. Espero me puedan ayudar ver mi error o en donde estoy mal, se los agradecería.

El problema es que ('Hola') no es una tupla con una cadena como único item, es una cadena sin más. Los paréntesis aquí son solo eso, no denotan una tupla. En este caso, datos = ('Hola') es exactamente lo mismo que datos = 'Hola':
>>> datos = ("Hola")
>>> datos
'Hola'
>>> type(datos)
<class 'str'>
>>> len(datos)
4

Dado que el segundo parámetro de execute() espera un iterable con los objetos a convertir para la query, al pasar "Hola" lo que hace es iterar sobre la cadena, con lo que la llamada equivale a:
cursor.execute(sql, ('H', 'o', 'l', 'a'))

como la query tiene un solo parámetro y le estamos pasando cuatro tenemos la excepción:

no se convierten todos los argumentos durante el formateo de cadena

De hecho, el error se puede reproducir usando formateo de cadenas "clásico":
>>> "¡%s a todos!" % ("H", "o", "l", "a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Para pasar una tupla hay que usar una coma en el literal tras el único item de la misma:
>>> datos = ("Hola",)  # <<<<<<<<<  
>>> datos
('Hola',)
>>> type(datos)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> len(datos)
1

La coma final solo es necesaria cuando el literal tiene un solo item:
>>> datos = ("Hola", "mundo")
>>> datos
('Hola', 'mundo')
>>> type(datos)
<class 'tuple'>


Nota
Para el intérprete lo que importa a la hora de definir una tupla mediante notación literal no son los paréntesis, es la coma. Los paréntesis son opcionales realmente (excepto para crear una tupla vacía):
>>> datos = 'Hola',
>>> datos
('Hola',)
>>> datos = 'Hola', 'mundo'
>>> datos
('Hola', 'mundo')

No obstante, es recomendable usar los paréntesis para evitar errores, ambigüedades y por legibilidad principalmente.
